# Populating select in html document using ajax (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Problem : I am trying to populate the 1st SELECT on load. And 2nd SELECT depends on the 1st one. 
1st select : populated with states
2nd select : should be populated with districts based on selected states.
jSON file is [HERE](https://github.com/sab99r/Indian-States-And-Districts/blob/master/states-and-districts.json) 
Solutions given on other stackoverflow documents didn't meet my requirements\

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    header:{' Access-Control-Allow-Origin ':'*'},
    datatype:'json',
    url:'https://github.com/sab99r/Indian-States-And-Districts/blob/master/states-and-districts.json'
  })
  .done(function(response){
    console.log(response);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="">
      <select class="states" >
      </select>
      <select class="districts" >
      </select>
    </div>
    <link rel="text/script" href="jquery-3.5.1.js">
    <link rel="text/>script" href="index.js">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: when your first select's result is ready( jQuery success function) , go for second request

Comment: can you please elaborate. i am not getting  you. are u saying to add success attribute after the url inside ajax ?

Comment: 1) you load json 2) *when* that json has finished loading, you then populate the `select`.  "when the json has loaded" is the "jquery success function" - in your code that's inside `done`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below example show an example how to load data, first and then store it in
a var to prevent ajax loading every change, then in every change fetch data array to load districts :

( uring raw url load text , so you have to pare json from string at first )

See wokring snippet :

```js
data = [];

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".states").on("change", stateChange);

  $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      header: {
        ' Access-Control-Allow-Origin ': '*'
      },
      datatype: 'json',
      url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sab99r/Indian-States-And-Districts/master/states-and-districts.json'
    })
    .done(function(response) {
      var resp = JSON.parse(response);
      loadStates(resp);
    })

});


var loadStates = function(response) {

  if (response.states) {
    data = response.states;

    response.states.forEach(state => {

      var option = $('<option/>');
      option.attr({
        'value': state.state,
      }).text(state.state);
      $('.states').append(option);
    })
  }
}

var stateChange = function(event) {
  let stateValue = event.target.value;
  let state = data.find(state => state.state === stateValue);
  
  $('.districts').html("");

  if (state) {

    state.districts.forEach(ditrict => {
      var option = $('<option/>');
      option.attr({
        'value': ditrict,
      }).text(ditrict);
      $('.districts').append(option);
    })

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
state :
<select class="states">
</select>
<br> distric
<select class="districts">
</select>
```

Comment: In case if i am loading a local json file. Then i need not to parse . right /

Comment: no it depends on the datatype return by your server , because here from github , it returned `text/plain` , so you have to return `application/json` from server then use without parse

Comment: yes. As you told i changed it to application/json and it's working fine. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just set code according to your requirement but you need to set all logic. You need to set when you send state data then you will get all districts

```js
function changeselect(){
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    header:{' Access-Control-Allow-Origin ':'*'},
    datatype:'json',
    url:'https://github.com/sab99r/Indian-States-And-Districts/blob/master/states-and-districts.json'
  })
  .done(function(response){
    console.log(response);
    response.foreach(function(data){
    $("#distr").append("<option>+data+</option>")
    })
  })
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    header:{' Access-Control-Allow-Origin ':'*'},
    datatype:'json',
    url:'https://github.com/sab99r/Indian-States-And-Districts/blob/master/states-and-districts.json'
  })
  .done(function(response){
    console.log(response);
    response.foreach(function(data){
    $("#distr").append("<option>+data+</option>")
    })
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="">
      <select class="states" onchange="changeselect()">
      <option>A</option>      
      <option>B</option>      
      <option>C</option>


      </select>
      <select class="districts" id="distr">
      </select>
    </div>
    <link rel="text/script" href="jquery-3.5.1.js">
    <link rel="text/>script" href="index.js">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @jeno if it work please accept my answer 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**I have got a even short code to do it.** 
We can use ajax GET to get data from the raw of any repository. 
Solution to the above question :

```
$.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aps08/web-development/main/web-dev-series/JSON/indian-states-and-cities.json',  // url
        function (data1, textStatus, jqXHR) {  // success callback
          var data1 = JSON.parse(data1);
          load(data1);
      });
```

*Remember that if u loading data from your local machine then you need to remove*
***var data1 =JSON.parse(data1)***   line